# Play Framework 2.4.x - Override Guice Binding

Tags: scala, playframework, guice

I have couple of test cases and there is one test case where I want to test the notification is not available. I used a separate `GuiceInjectorBuilder` to inject (override) the notification service instance to `None` instead of the usual `Some(DefaultNotificationService)`

```
class MySpec extends PlaySpec with Results with OneAppPerSuite {
  def appController = Application.instanceCache[AppController].apply(app)

  // typical case
  "cancel an order" should {
      "return HTTP OK" in {        
        val result: Future[Result] = injector.instanceOf[AppController].cancel(1).apply(FakeRequest())
        status(result) mustEqual OK
        (contentAsJson(result) \ "message").as[String] mustEqual "Order no. 1 is cancelled"
      }
    }

    // exception case 
    "cancel an order but notification service is OUT" should {
      import play.api.inject.bind

      val injector = new GuiceInjectorBuilder()
        .bindings(new MockAppModule)
        .in(Mode.Test)
        .overrides(bind[Option[NotificationService]].toInstance(None))  // usually it is configured to Some(DefaultNotificaionService)
        .injector()

      "return HTTP Multi Status" in {
        val result: Future[Result] = injector.instanceOf[AppController].update(1).apply(FakeRequest())
        status(result) mustEqual MULTI_STATUS
        (contentAsJson(result) \ "message").as[String] mustEqual "Order no. 1 is cancelled but user does not know"
      }
    }

  ...
  }
```

It did not work because `MockAppModule` depends on other modules injected by Play during its startup lifecycle for this test. How do I load these Play default modules for `MockAppModule` to work for this test case? Is there a better way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do this with one app per test, instead of per suite, you could try overriding the binding like this (there might be an equivalent method to `newAppForTest()`, to do this with one app per suite):

```
class MySpec extends PlaySpec with Results with GuiceOneAppPerTest {

implicit override def newAppForTest(testData: TestData): Application = {
    GuiceApplicationBuilder()
        .overrides(bind[Option[NotificationService]].toInstance(None))  // usually it is configured to Some(DefaultNotificaionService)
        .build()
    }
}
```